# Like clause in JPA 2 TypedQuery works only for some name params and for others not

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm currently having a little issue with JPA 2 and Typed Query.
I'm creating a search feature in my project using LIKE clause, however when I try to search for a string like "marina" it no works, it works only when I type "marin", even when exists in the database the name marina.

This is my code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("select u from User u"
                + " where (u.login LIKE :regex OR u.fullname LIKE :regex)"
                + " AND (u.status <> :status)"
                + " order by u.fullname");

        TypedQuery<User> query = jpaAPI.em().createQuery(builder.toString(),User.class);
        query.setParameter("status", statusTypeDeleted());
        query.setParameter("regex", "%"+regex+"%");
        query.setFirstResult(init);
        query.setMaxResults(end);
```

So, does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: I do not know if it helps, but you should have your % characters in query string, not in parameter, because parameters are escaped.

Comment: Just a comment, the point of using `StringBuilder` is to *not* concatenate strings like this: `str1 + str2 + ...`. Use [append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method instead.

Comment: and if fixing the % doesnt work then look in the log at the SQL invoked and it should show you your error

Comment: @dic19 when the string is a constant with no parameters and you use `+` it gets concatenated at compile time. The `StringBuilder` can just be removed in this case. As for the question: What do you mean it doesn't work? If there are no strings that match `%marina%`, then it's not going to show any results. And if toy do intend to use a regex, the MySQL keyword for it is `RLIKE`, but that might fail with a JPQL query and you'd have to use native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved this problem right now.
The problem is on this line:

```
query.setFirstResult(init);
```

The value I was passing to this method was 1 instead 0. How just exist only one entity with name "marina", the query result nothing, since the first result should be 0.